# How to get my method to return it's resulting values to a 3rd method

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure if the topic title is specific enough but here goes.  I have two methods - one that iterates through some arrays along with conditionals in the block to push the correct data out.

Here is that code

```
def iterate_lines
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.each_with_index do |line,index|
    lines = @board[line[0]] + @board[line[1]] + @board[line[2]]
      if lines.include?("X") && !lines.include?("O")
        scores = tally_scores(lines.count("X"),"X",index)
          elsif lines.include?("O") && !lines.include?("X")
        scores = tally_scores(lines.count("O"),"O",index)
          elsif lines.include?("X") && lines.include?("O")
        scores = tally_scores(0,"",index)
          elsif !lines.include?("X") && !lines.include?("O")
        scores = tally_scores(0,"",index)
      end
      p scores
  end
end
```

The other method is the one calculating those scores according to my chosen heuristics.

```
def tally_scores(score,player,index)
  score =    1 if score == 1 && player == "X"
  score =   -1 if score == 1 && player == "O"
  score =   10 if score == 2 && player == "X"
  score =  -10 if score == 2 && player == "O"
  score =  100 if score == 3 && player == "X"
  score = -100 if score == 3 && player == "O"  
  score
end
```

Calling 'iterate_lines I can print the correct values out from either 'tally_scores', or as I have shown here, by setting the variables 'scores' to the calls in 'iterate_lines', which allows me to just print them out from 'iterate_lines'.

Naturally the return values from 'iterate_lines' is the array (WIN_COMBINATIONS).  Hard-coding a `return scores` obviously would give me just the last value.

My problem is I have a 3rd method that needs to get what comes out of 'tally_scores' yet I can't pass it over as a regular argument, aka `my_method(scores)`.  The reason being is that the 3rd method has it's own list of arguments it gets passed for other reasons. Plus it would be nil until the method was called.

```
def get_scores
  # other code
  #: something like this:
  score = iterate_lines 
  # or
  score = tally_scores
  # or
  # ?
end
```

So I feel like maybe I backed myself into a corner and should trash what I have and restart.  I will say I tried taking 'tally_scores' and putting the scores into a instance variable array.  I found though when I passed it, all but the last value remained.

Comment: never hurts to use an explicit `return` when you have something like this.

Comment: sure, I've tried explicit return but doesn't get me anywhere.  I mean all it is doing for me is getting one value.

Comment: Is this tic-tac-toe? If so I can't figure out what you're doing, in part because some of the code is missing (`WIN_COMBINATIONS` and `@board`). A few observations: 1) the block variable `index` is not used; 2) rather than the method `talley_scores` you could use the hash  `{ [1, "X"]=>1, [1, "O"]=>-1, [2, "X"]=>10, [2, "O"]=>-10, [3, "X"]=>100, [3, "X"]=>-100 }`; 3) it's probably best to start by counting `"X"`'s and  `"O"`'s in rows, columns and diagonals and 4) if ttt, calculating scores seems an odd approach.

Comment: Yes,it's ttt, well for whatever zero-sum game.  So, I didn't want to make this post about ttt though which is mostly why I didn't post the other code.  The `WIN_COMBINATIONS` are the lines` [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],.....[2,4,6]]`, `@board` is the array that holds the markers.  I'm not sure this is an odd approach though, I've found a number of 2 player games using a combination of heuristics and minimax implementation.  This is just my attempt at it.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland  I was also going to say is that the score and the index will go into a hash, however the hash is not going to be created prior to the minimax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here. First of all, as you've seen when you use `each_with_index` nothing that happens in that block has an effect outside, unless you use side effects. If you a set a variable in that block it will be reset each iteration.

You can change it to `map.with_index` so that the result is an array of the results produced by the iterations.

Also it seems like `scores` should be `score` here and in lines similar to it, since `tally_scores` returns a single score:

```
scores = tally_scores(lines.count("X"),"X",index)
```

If you're using `map.with_index`, then the return value of the block should be `score`, that way the result will be an array of scores. However you can't use `return score` from the block, which will return from the parent *method* and not the single iteration of the block. You can use `next score` instead or simply `score` as the last line.

After making these changes, you can say `scores = iterate_lines`.

It would look something like this:

```
def iterate_lines
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.map.with_index do |line, index|
    # set score according to your conditional logic
    score # or alternatively, "next score"
  end
end
```

It's better to extract the printing logic to elsewhere, for example:

```
scores = iterate_lines
scores.each { |score| p score }
```

Comment: Works great! I had a feeling that map would be useful but I didn't know `map.with_index` was something possible.